# Arduino String not working inside FreeRTOS Task

Tags: c++, arduino, freertos

I am trying to read Serial data on Arduino Mega 2560 using built in String object but its not printing the Serial data when used inside a FreeRTOS task like following code

```
void TaskSerialIn(void *pvParameters)
{
    String json;

    for(;;) {
        while(Serial.available()) {
            json = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
            Serial.println(json); // this code not printing anything
        }

        vTaskDelay(200 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work even if I declare the String as global variable.
Whereas the following code works when character array is used to store the bytes

```
char serialJson[65];

void TaskSerialIn(void *pvParameters)
{
    char * jsonStr;
    int i = 0;

    for(;;) {
        i = 0;

        while(Serial.available()) {
            char inChar = (char) Serial.read();
            serialJson[i++] = inChar;
            if(inChar == '\n') {
                serialJson[i] = '\0';
                Serial.print(serialJson);
            }
        }

        vTaskDelay(200 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on how could I use String to read the Serial data.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What do you see exactly?

Comment: Polling for reading data on a serial port can be controlled better when the sender is sending data char by char rather than string as in your second example. First example bug looks more like a synchronization issue.

Comment: @TisteAndii    I commented on the first code snippet mentioning which line isn't printing anything while it is expected to print. I updated the post.

Comment: If you combine the fact that readStringUntil has a timeout of 1s and also discards any chars collected after a call, it is likely that you're just missing the delimiters. Why do you need to use Arduino Strings? C strings are more efficient and reliable without any potential memory issues.